# Удаление запятой и точки, букв в цене

Tags: javascript

Есть цена, она выглядит как `4,890 руб.`, как из этого получить `4890`?

Comment: Это типа скидка? =)

Comment: тут у меня уже прописан код, который к цене сразу прибавляет стоимость атрибута.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала регулярным выражением получаем нужные нам циферки, потом в полученном значении удаляем запятые.

```
var price = "4,890 руб";
price = price.match(/^(.*?)\sруб/)[1].replace(",", "");
```

Если Вам нужно из строки сделать число, тогда так:

```
var price = "4,890 руб";
price = parseInt(price.match(/^(.*?)\sруб/)[1].replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: а что делать с руб.
? Это одна переменная

Comment: Обновил пример

Answer (score 5):

Регулярное выражение `.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,'');` оставляет только цифры в строке

```
var temp = new String('567,545/? usd!!!');
document.write(temp + '<br>'); // -> 567,545/? usd!!!
temp =  temp.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,'');
document.write(temp + '<br>'); // -> 567545
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/TTfzu/24/)

---

```
"4,890 руб.".replace(/[^\d]+/g,'') + " USD"; //4890 USD
```

Comment: Ваш пример, пожалуй, предпочтительнее, чем мой :]

Comment: или [^\d] вместо [^0-9]

Comment: nolka, Vitalii Maslianok, Yura Ivanov  Спасибо

а не подскажите, теперь как к полученному результату приписать в конце, например  "USD"

Comment: В моем случае:
price = price+" USD";

Comment: Вот такой еще вариант, удаляет точки и запятые только если справа и слева стоят цифры. На таком примере будет показан хороший результат  
> У тебя есть 5,000, м? А еще лучше 10,000.
Результат.  
> У тебя есть 5000, м? А еще лучше 10000.

    replace( /(?<=\d)[.,](?=\d)/g, "")